# Posting accented characters in .netcore2.1 web-api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm doing a web-api in .net core 2.1 (C#) and I've been having problems to send accented characters in a POST request.

So far I've tried two differents approachs: building the content that will be posted using FormUrlEncodedContent and StringContent. I've used references from https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/121713/applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-com-httpwebrequest (in portuguese). 
I guess I'm having trouble with the UTF-8 encoding for some reason.

Using FormUrlEncodedContent:

```
        var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        object[] myKeys = new object[content.DsValues.Count];
        object[] myValues = new object[content.DsValues.Count];

        content.DsValues.Keys.CopyTo(myKeys, 0);
        content.DsValues.Values.CopyTo(myValues, 0);

        foreach (object value in myValues)
        {
            values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("value", value.ToString()));
        }

        foreach (object key in myKeys)
        {
            values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("field", key.ToString()));
        }

        values.AddRange(content.Values);

        var string_message = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values).ReadStringAsync();

        var postRequest = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string_message);
        request.ContentLength = postRequest.Length;
        var stream = request.GetRequestStream();
        stream.Write(postRequest, 0, postRequest.Length);
        stream.Close();
```

Using StringContent:

```
        var formurlstring = "";
        foreach(object value in myValues)
        {
            formurlstring = formurlstring + "value=" + value.ToString() + "&";
        }

        foreach(object key in myKeys)
        {
            formurlstring = formurlstring + "field=" + key.ToString() + "&";
        }

        var encoded = formurlstring.Replace(" ", "+");
        var string_message = new StringContent(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(encoded));


        var postRequest = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string_message);
        request.ContentLength = postRequest.Length;
        var stream = request.GetRequestStream();
        stream.Write(postRequest, 0, postRequest.Length);
        stream.Close();
```

As far as I've checked, the string returned by FormUrlEncodedContent has the accented characters already encoded, while the string I'm recovering from StringContent still has the accented characters. I can post both of them to an outside webapplication, but whenever I go check what I've posted, the accented characters are not correct. I would be expecting something like:

COMESTÍVEL

But whenever I go check on the website what has been posted is something like:
COMESTÃVEL

Thanks in advance for the replies and sorry if I've forgot some information about the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally debugged it down.

So, since I'm working with ISO-8859-1, I had to change my encoding method to it. Whenever I tried to create the content to be uploaded using FormUrlEncodeContent or StringContent, the encode being used was not the right one.

So, instead of using those methods to create my content, I did it inside loops and sent back the pure string and then I encoded it with the right encoding method.

```
var formurlstring = "";
        foreach(object value in myValues)
        {
            formurlstring = formurlstring + "value=" + value.ToString() + "&";
        }

        foreach(object key in myKeys)
        {
            formurlstring = formurlstring + "field=" + key.ToString() + "&";
        }

        var string_message = formurlstring.Replace(" ", "+");

        var enc8859 = Encoding.GetEncoding(28591);
        var postRequest = enc8859.GetBytes(string_message);
        request.ContentLength = postRequest.Length;
        var stream = request.GetRequestStream();
        stream.Write(postRequest, 0, postRequest.Length);
        stream.Close();
```

There's probably a better way to do it. I did want to use it with the FormUrlEncodedContent, which is way simpler and cleaner, but since I wasn't able to...

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the `Content-Type` header for your post request has the mime-type with `charset=UTF-8` included. Right now, it's being interpreted as ASCII (latin-1).

Comment: I was using
          `request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";`
But even after changing it to
            `request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";`
I'm still receiving it on the wrong charset after posting it.

Comment: What is your client?

Comment: I'm forced to use Internet Explore 10, since the website I'm posting is quite old.

Comment: Actually, I've just realized the `Content-Type is ISO-8859-1`. But even after changing my `request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";` to `request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=ISO-8859-1";` I still have the same problem.